# grails gorm how to do a join with a 3 table hierarchy

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My web interface has an ajax call to update a photo's caption.  A post sends the caption and the publicId of the photo to a service.

```
The service has 

Photo photo = Photo.findByPublicId(params.publicId)
photo.caption = params.caption
photo.save()
```

However I have read in Burt Beckwith's grails book this is not secure.  As-is a hacker could post any publicId to my service and update the
caption of a photo that doesn't not belong to their session.  I need some GORM advice on how to write the update query to update only photos belonging
to the current user's session.  Due to the number of joins involved I am lost.  I am familiar with getting the profile/user:

```
    User user = User.load(springSecurityService.principal.id)

    Profile profile = Profile.findByUser(user, [lock:true])
```

but not the one query that would join everything for the entire update, instead of Profile.findByUser(user, [lock:true]).photoAlbum.getPhotoWherePublicId(publicId) or something that seems it would make 4 different sql calls.

The domain schema I have with the hierarchy in question is :

```
//user from springsecurity for session/login management
class User {
   //no reference to profile
}

class Profile {
   PhotoAlbum photoAlbum
   User user //reference to user

   static constraints = {
       photoAlbum(nullable:true)
   }
}

class PhotoAlbum {
   static hasMany = [photos:Photo]
   static belongsTo = [profile:Profile]
}

class Photo {
   static belongsTo = PhotoAlbum
   String caption
   String publicId
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with a criteria or namedQuerie this could be done.
Something like this may work:

First make a small change to your Photo class

```
class Photo {
   PhotoAlbum photoAlbum
   static belongsTo = [photoAlbum: PhotoAlbum]
   String caption
   String publicId
}
```

and try with this criteria

```
Photo.withCriteria{
  eq 'id',params.publicId
  photoAlbum {
    eq 'profile',profile
  } 
}
```

Comment: `PhotoAlbum photoAlbum` is not necessary in your example